# Segue to popover for iPhone not working in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

I wanted to segue to a popover in iOS 10, this piece of code used to work fine on iPhone but not now (it shows full screen), what have I done wrong? The segue is set to "Present As Popover".

```
 override func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject!) {  
    if segue.identifier == "about" {  
        let aboutController = segue.destination as! AboutController  
        aboutController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width:300, height:440)  

        let popoverController = aboutController.popoverPresentationController  

        if popoverController != nil {  
            popoverController!.delegate = self  
            popoverController!.backgroundColor = UIColor.black  
        }  
    }  
}  

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {  
    return .none  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many function have been renamed in Swift 3, including `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` - this is now `adaptivePresentationStyle(for:)`

Change your code to

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller:UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Since your function name didn't match it wasn't being called and because it is an optional function in the protocol, you didn't get a warning.

Comment: Nice one cheers - one of the reasons that optional protocol methods can sometimes cause issues :)

Comment: Has this stopped working in iOS 11? I can only get the popover to display modally on iPhone

Answer (score -4):

Popover is an iPad only feature.
UIKit is smart enough to figure out it should present it modally on iPhone/iPod.

Comment: That is the default behaviour, but you can change this through `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` as the OP has done.  Their question seems to be "Why doesn't this work in iOS 10 as it did in earlier versions of iOS and how can I fix it?"